# Redirect after res.end() in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i am using jsonwebtoken to authenticate user. 
my plan is to save the token at header and then get the header value before any request made . yes i did save the value in header at login successfully but it should redirect to other page like any other app do. i tried redirect or render other page and getting the error

> Can't set headers after they are sent.

```
apiRoutes.post('/authenticate', function(req, res) {

 User.findOne({
 name: req.body.name
  }, function(err, user) {

   if (err) throw err;

if (!user) {
  res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.' });
} else if (user) {


  if (user.password != req.body.password) {
    res.json({ success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.' });
  } else {
    var token = jwt.sign(user, app.get('superSecret'), {
     expiresInMinutes: 60 // expires in 4 hours
    });


  var body = "hello world";
     res.writeHead(200, {
     "Content-Length": body.length,
     "Content-Type": "text/plain",
     "x-access-token":token
 });


     res.end();
     console.log('token saved '+res.getHeader('x-access-token'));

  }   

}

 });
});
```

here is the complete project [project](https://github.com/nurfarazi/nodejs-web-token.git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't make sense.  An http response has exactly one status code.  It is EITHER your JSON data with a 200 status OR a 302 status with a Location header set.  It simply cannot be both.  Pick one.

If you want, you can put a location to redirect to in your JSON response and have the client manually go to that redirect location after it processes the JSON response.

You could put a location header in the 200 response if you want, but the browser won't automatically follow that.

Also, if this request is an Ajax call from the browser, the browser won't change the page just because you send a redirect response.  Your code that receives the Ajax call would have to change the page itself.

In addition, `res.json(...)` sends the response immediately so you can't write more after sending that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me...

```
res.writeHead(200, {
     "Content-Length": body.length,
     "Content-Type": "text/plain",
     "x-access-token":token,
     "Location": "http://www.google.com"
})
```